# Excel 2010 Conditional formating highlight a different cell with the reference cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

How can I highlight another cell (`B2`) the same color as cell `B13`. `B13` has a `countif` formula (`=COUNTIF(B5:C11,$AA2)`) built into it.

- If the count is between 1 & 2, then `B13` will turn red.
- If the count is between 3 & 5, then `B13` will turn yellow
- If the count is 5 or more, `B13` will turn green.

I would like `B2` to be the same color as `B13` without changing the values (dates) in B2.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply reference B13 in a conditional formatting formula for B2, e.g. select B2 and then use a formula like

`=B13>4`

format green

`=B13>2`

format yellow

`=B13>=0`

format red

You need to make sure those conditions appear in that order (you can adjust the order within CF)